# Mysterious global variables - COM/STA Apartment Object

Tags: c++, dll, com, components, atl

Here's the scenario:

-COM DLL, loaded into the address space of the process that uses the DLL.
-Inside the DLL couple global variables exist (lets say var a, var b) and a global function.
-Process starts up, calls the global function and initializes globals a, b and calls CoInitialize(NULL) - The thread is an STA.
-Then same global function creates an STA COM object

Later in the program, same thread (the thread that called CoInitialize above and created STA COM object) calls same global C-Function (lets call it func()) in this DLL. In the scope of the C-function the state of the global variables is exactly as expected (ie. correctly initialized). 
The minute the function func() invokes a COM method on the existing STA COM object, the COM object being in the same DLL sees completely different copies of the global variables (var a, var b). I took the address of both variables and they are completely different in the C-func as opposed to invoked COM objects function.
What is going on? I thought globals in same address space should be visible across the board.

Comment: A DLL should *never* call CoInitializeEx(), it didn't create the thread.  Check the return value, odds are good it failed.  Funny stuff now happens when you create the COM server.  The EXE must get the thread right.

Comment: Actually that's not correct. It doesn't matter whether it is DLL or exe or whatever, COM services stipulates that a thread that uses COM object must call CoInitialize always, regardless of its location. Btw, the call succeeds the COM object is created successfully and the method on COM object succeeds also.

Comment: No, you only *hope* that the EXE didn't already call CoInitializeEx().  Many do.

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678543\(VS.85\).aspx) says this: `Typically, the COM library is initialized on a thread only once. Subsequent calls to CoInitialize or CoInitializeEx on the same thread will succeed, as long as they do not attempt to change the concurrency model, but will return S_FALSE.` and `the first thread in the application that calls CoInitialize with 0 (or CoInitializeEx with COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED) must be the last thread to call CoUninitialize.`

Comment: Thats exactly what happens. The process is actually 3rd party app that does not interact with COM. In the middle of the program it calls my plugin DLL. In that plugin DLL I initialize COM services only once per thread. Everything is just fine in the regard. So my point is it doesnt matter the location (DLL, EXE), what matters that the thread calls Coinitialize once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that two instances of your DLL are being loaded -- one explicitly by the application that hosts your DLL, and the second through the COM subsystem via CoCreateInstance.  The former will look in the DLL search path for the application's process, while the latter will look in the registry for the location of the COM component that implements your COCLASS.

If your DLL has a DllMain (or the InitInstance function if it's an MFC-based DLL), then you can breakpoint it and look at the hinstance argument (or AfxGetInstanceHandle if MFC) to see if (a) you initialize twice and (b) you see two different DLL instance handles.  If so, then you're definitely loading twice.

The DLL's location in the file system matters, so you should see if there are copies in separate locations that might be separately loaded based on the rules I mentioned above.

In general, a COM DLL should never be loaded directly.  You should break your functionality up into two DLLs, with a COM server DLL dedicated to the COM stuff.  You can provide yourself an internal COCLASS interface that will enable you to pass your globals to the COM DLL, if you so wish.

Comment: That's possible but I would not think that should of happened. If the DLL is already loaded why would COM services loaded again? Anyway I check the Handles; I am not sure if I can do it since I am using ATL and it uses pile of code. To answer ur other question why not separate the code from COM: Well, there's more to it that I with held and would take a page to write. Anyways, Ill take a look.

Comment: OK, checked the handles, COM services does map a separate instance of the DLL into the same address space. Therefore, the process has 2 DLLs at the end. I guess I am not going to interfere with this and go with the suggestion to have my COM server in separate DLL and then try to figure out how to handle data exchange because I do have quite a bit of data to move. Thanks for everyone's help